# command line grep * does not work but grep *. works

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

How come "staff*22" does not show anything while "staff.*22" lists lines that contain staff followed by 22 although any of the lines does not contain "." in them?

```
$ ls -l | grep "staff*22"
$ ls -l | grep "staff.*22"
drwxrwxr-x  2 kim  staff   68 Jan 12 22:23 hihi
drwxrwxrwx  4 kim  staff  136 Jan 12 22:29 temp2
drwxrwxrwx  3 kim  staff  102 Jan 12 22:41 tes2
```

Comment: `man grep` and see the details about regular expressions and `.` = `[^\n]` = any char except newline.

Comment: You may be confusing *regular expressions* with *shell globs* - see for example [Globs compared to regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Compared_to_regular_expressions)

Comment: What is the rule that you're trying to do here ? I mean, are you trying to find all files that belong to `staff` group and end with number 2 in filename ?

Comment: I am trying to find lines that contain staff and followed by 22 in terms of regular expressions, not globs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What do given grep commands do

From your output it is apparent that you want to find all files that belong to "staff" group and created at hour 22 ( or 10 pm in 12 hour format ). We'll address that below, but lets first figure out what your `grep` commands do and why they're not the right tool for what you want.

First of all, the two `grep` commands that you do are slightly different in the way they are interpreted, and your approach is not proper - you shouldn't try to [parse output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

- `grep "staff*22"` reads as "match all lines that start with 'staf' and may or may not have in them extra 'f' , immediately followed by '22'."

  ```
  $ echo "staff whatever 22" | grep 'staff*22'               
  $ echo "staff22" | grep 'staf*22'                          
  staff22
  $ echo "staf22" | grep 'staff*22'                         
  staf22
  $ echo "staf22" | grep 'staff*22'
  staf22
  ```
- `grep "staff.*22"` reads as "match all lines that have 'staff' in them, zero or more characters in between ( any type of character ),and number 22".

  ```
  $  echo "staff whatever 22" | grep 'staff.*22'                                                                           
  staff whatever 22
  ```

#### Better approach

`ls` command in general should only be used for interactive listing, i.e., when you only want to have a quick peek at what's inside a folder. When it is necessary to find specific files, or some how work with those files via script, `find` command is the way to go. It has `-group` variable, which will help you isolate all the files that belong to `staff` group, and `-nevermt` for finding files with modification time newer than some specific date. For instance, what you want is probably this:

```
find . -group staff -newermt "2017-01-12 21:59:59"
```

See also this: https://superuser.com/questions/580273/ubuntu-linux-find-files-between-specific-times

Comment: @Mint.K You're welcome :) I'll add a few other things, but hopefully, I've answered the core of your question

Comment: Please do so. I'd like to learn more.

Comment: @Mint.K  Edited, please review :)

Comment: Can you give me some references to ".*"? does "." in ".*" mean anything in between? I am trying to figure out if there is something like a table that explains such symbols mentioned above.

Comment: @Mint.K there's plenty of references online, simplest would be just go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression. The `.` means any character. `*` means previous element repeated zero or more times. So in `ab.*c`  it means match any string which has  `ab` characters , which may have something after them, followed by `c`.